# Google Sheets can't make a formula that identifies cells having a 0 in it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make a formula that changes the color of a row based on the number in a cell. All of the numbers that I'm using are all in column G.

I got it to work by using Conditional Formatting, format cells if, the custom formula is, and then the formula `=$G1=3` (and more formulas with the number going down each time). All of the formulas from `=$G1=3` to `=$G1=1` all work as I expect but when I try to use `=$G1=0`, all the rows that have either 0 in it or is just empty.

I have also tried to use `=$G1="0"` and that doesn't work either. I can get it to work if I use Format cell if, the text is exactly, 0 or Format cell if, is equal to, 0. But, using these only change the color of the cell that has 0 in any cell.

```
=$G1=3
=$G1=2
=$G1=1
```

Is there a way to make a formula that checks if a cell has 0 in it using a custom formula? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this custom formula:

```
=($G1=0)*($G1<>"")
```

[image: 0]